# Creating Choropleth map in plotly with latitude and longitude

Tags: plotly, latitude-longitude, choropleth

I wanted to know if it is possible to create a choropleth map using plotly in python with latitude and longitude as locations. What would be the locationmode in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I am supposed reading [plotly docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#choropleth-locationmode), parameter `locationmode` would be `countrynames`. That means, you should see the full world map or chunks of map, depends on your passed data. This [example](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-inset-map) can show map of Africa. So if you want select particular country, you can look and setup necessary parameters (`lon` and `lat`) in `Scattergeo`, where you can choose langitude and latitude as you want

Comment: Thank you. Your solution probably would have worked as well. But I finally used a scatter plot on map, as done here: https://plot.ly/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/#north-american-precipitation-map

Comment: This link https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-inset-map is not there any more, no Africa map example